# debugging bastion-linux template failure "The following resource(s) failed to create: [BastionAutoScalingGroup]" with awscli

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to follow this [procedure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/linux-bastion/welcome.html) to place a bastion-linux host into an existing vpc.

However, it's now failing with the message as the `StackStatusReason`:

`The following resource(s) failed to create: [BastionAutoScalingGroup]`

How can I debug the reason from this further using the awscli?